# Authorization scope does not appear

Tags: google-fit

I created a new app and the authentication part for GoogleFit is a complete copy/paste of another app that works perfectly. The window to choose an account appears but after that I'm expecting to see the window that showing needed scope but nothing.

Is there someone who already encountered this issue ?

I can post my code if needed.

Thanks a lot !

**Edit**

This is my code to connect to Google Fit:

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    // Create the Google API Client
        mFitClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
                .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
                .addScope(new Scope((Scopes.FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE)))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to Fitness API!!!");
                                                // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                                // Put application specific code here.
                                                // Once connected go the Main2Activity
                                                Intent start_google_plus = new Intent(GoogleFitAuthentication.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(start_google_plus);
                                                finish();
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionSuspend");
                                                // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                                // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                                if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                                } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                )
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                                                   // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                                                       Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
                                                       if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                                                           // Show the localized error dialog
                                                           GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
                                                                   GoogleFitAuthentication.this, 0).show();
                                                           return;
                                                       }
                                                       // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
                                                       // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
                                                       // authorization dialog is displayed to the user.
                                                       if (!authInProgress) {
                                                           try {
                                                               Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                                                               authInProgress = true;
                                                               result.startResolutionForResult(GoogleFitAuthentication.this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
                                                           } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                                               Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                   }
                                               }
                )
                .build();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Processing onActivityResult...");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH");
        authInProgress = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "resultCode == RESULT_OK");
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mFitClient.isConnecting() && !mFitClient.isConnected()) {
                mFitClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Impossible to process onActivityResult...");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect to the Fitness API
    Log.i(TAG, "Connecting...");
    if(mFitClient!=null){
        mFitClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop...");
    if (mFitClient!=null && mFitClient.isConnected()) {
        mFitClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(AUTH_PENDING, authInProgress);
}
```

Comment: show your copy/paste code first... maybe you've copied some app id...

Comment: I found the issue. In the google api console there is a misprint in the package name !

Answer (score 0):

When you authorized the scopes , the browser will store your session. So if you again authorize the app in the same browser, you will only shows the scope as **Have offline access**.